# Validate Mobile Number Pattern

Tags: html

I want to validate a mobile number...It starts with 0 and the next three digits pattern is 1 to 7 number and then a '-' between the next starting number with 7 digits starts with 0 to 9 
The pattern I want to follow is that :
0333-1234567
0312-3342090

Comment: anything u have tried any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pattern="[0][1-7]{3}[-][0-9]{7}"
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7wL3M/1/)